# App store release fails to load

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I just released my latest PhoneGap build to the app store and now when I download it, it fails to load, only showing the splash screen and spinner. I'm not sure how to collect an error, other than running it with the console open. Also there are no crash logs under organizer.

I also checked the entitlements and aps-enviroment was on production.

The only error is this and I can't figure out what it means: `The 'Passive' connection 'MYAPP' access to protected services is denied.`

I gathered all of the certificates (I hope) and Push notifications are enabled on the App ID on the dev center. Everything is working fine on my local builds.

There is from the console on startup:

```
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[3035] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/D79CBF76-D2DE-49E2-8021-BDA8EFB7EC0E (sandbox)
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone backboardd[31] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'MYAPP' access to protected services is denied.
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 10.690987ms
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 0.021994ms
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 12.279987ms
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264722.812325]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264722.812654]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: networkd sharingd SiriViewService apsd lockdownd assistantd 
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264722.892555]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: appDel.globalToken :<123 456 token here 789>
Apr  3 17:38:42 Adams-iPhone MYAPP[3035] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/D79CBF76-D2DE-49E2-8021-BDA8EFB7EC0E/MYAPP.app/www/index.html
```

Pause in text streaming, app splash screen is just spinning

```
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3033] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: Not monitoring for external power.
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3033] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3033] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x14c6213d0>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3033] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: mstreamd starting up.
Apr  3 17:38:52 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon starting...
Apr  3 17:38:56 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264736.223622]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: Not monitoring for external power.
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x13ce433b0>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3037] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3038] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: mstreamd starting up.
Apr  3 17:39:32 Adams-iPhone mstreamd[3038] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon starting...
Apr  3 17:39:46 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264786.075727]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
Apr  3 17:39:57 Adams-iPhone wifid[40] <Notice>: WiFi:[418264797.335924]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"
```

Also some diffs from the additions for push: ([taken from this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575688/how-can-i-pass-the-devicetoken-string-to-webviewdidfinishload))

```
platforms/ios/Blonk/Classes/AppDelegate.m

@synthesize globalToken = _globalToken;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
@@ -87,10 +94,28 @


// TODO dump device token to console
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
//  NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    _globalToken = deviceToken;

//        NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert('push:ios %@')", deviceToken];
  //      [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
// Dump error message
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

platforms/ios/Blonk/Classes/MainViewController.m

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"

  AppDelegate * appDel = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSLog(@"appDel.globalToken :%@", appDel.globalToken);


  NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__IOS_TOKEN__ = '%@';", appDel.globalToken];

  [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the code signing profile.

I upgraded Xcode to 5.1 which broke PhoneGap when building for the 5s. I downgraded to 5.0 and the release code signing was switched back to 'developer'. At the time I was not using TestFlight to make sure the binary I was submitting was running. I naively assumed the dev build was the same as the app store build. I was able to replicate the white screen problem using the bad build on TestFlight, and the new build with the proper profile worked on TestFlight, as well as from the app store.

If you haven't already, request an expedited review once you have a working build (I would test on TestFlight).